# How can i log host headers of http requests (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, http, logging, request, request-headers

I need to see what are the host headers for all request going through my Spring Boot app. I tried logging all request headers but i can't seem to log host headers.

Comment: please add what code you have written. also clearly add what you are getting and what you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a filter, and you will be able to see every header available. Here's a sample code:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

    public RequestFilter() {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpRequest.getHeaderNames(); //print this to see all headers

        httpRequest.getHeader("host"); //returns the host header
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

sample code to print all headers.

```
@GetMapping("/headers")
    public String getHeaders(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {
        headers.forEach((key, value) -> {
            System.out.println(String.format("Header '%s' = %s", key, value));
        });
     return "success";
    }
```

this would help you!